# Cascading timers and an async function in jest

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, asynchronous, jestjs

In this test code,

```
test('test', async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();

  const cb = jest.fn();
  const func = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(1);

  setTimeout(async () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      cb();
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);

  jest.runAllTimers();
});
```

since `jest.runAllTimers()` simulates enough passing time so that `cb()` is hit. But in this one,

```
test('test', async () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();

  const cb = jest.fn();
  const func = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(1);

  setTimeout(async () => {
    await func();
    setTimeout(() => {
      cb();
    }, 1000);
  }, 1000);

  jest.runAllTimers();

  expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

`cb()` is never hit.

How should I modify this test this code, so that it properly hits `cb` and the test passes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timer is defined after the promise (returned from `func`) is resolved. So   in order to run that timer you have to await for it to be initiated. You can do that by awaiting on the promise returned by `func`.

To access the data retuned by a jest mock function you can use it's [`.mock` property](https://jestjs.io/docs/mock-functions#mock-property)

e.g.

```
test('test', async () => {
    jest.useFakeTimers();
  
    const cb = jest.fn();
    const func = jest.fn().mockResolvedValueOnce(1);
  
    setTimeout(async () => {
      await func();
      setTimeout(() => {
        cb();
      }, 1000);
    }, 1000);
  
    jest.runAllTimers();
    await func.mock.results[0].value
    jest.runAllTimers();
  
    expect(cb).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```